# "No such file or directory"? Can't push a file with `adb`

Tags: command-line, android, adb

```
antonio@antonio-N150P-N210P-N220P:~$ adb push rom.zip /sdcard/
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
cannot stat 'rom.zip': No such file or directory
antonio@antonio-N150P-N210P-N220P:~$ adb push rom.zip /sdcard/
cannot stat 'rom.zip': No such file or directory
antonio@antonio-N150P-N210P-N220P:~$ ll ~/Downloads
total 573408
drwxr-xr-x  2 antonio antonio      4096 Jan 13 16:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 19 antonio antonio      4096 Jan 13 16:29 ../
-rwxrwxr-x  1 antonio antonio 587156866 Jan 13 16:00 rom.zip*
antonio@antonio-N150P-N210P-N220P:~$
```

I can't use `adb` correctly.

Comment: 1 thing: there is a * behind "rom.zip". Why?

Comment: `cannot stat 'rom.zip': No such file or directory` printed very clearly. :)

Comment: @Rinzwind look at the permissions, he's set it to executable

Answer (score 1):

Your `rom.zip` is in `Downloads`, but you are pushing files from your home directory  ( That is evident by looking at your prompt , where you have `~` before `$`. )

```
antonio@antonio-N150P-N210P-N220P:~$ adb push rom.zip /sdcard/
```

Do this:

```
antonio@antonio-N150P-N210P-N220P:~$ adb push ~/Downloads/rom.zip /sdcard/
```

Comment: Does `adb push` and `adb pull` require rooted Android device?